# Bayesian Statistics in CS229

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics

In this [note](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes5.pdf),there is a posterior distribution of parameter $\theta$ in section 3 like this:
$$
\begin{align}
p(\theta|S)&={p(S|\theta)p(\theta)\over p(S)}\\&={\big(\prod_{i=1}^mp(y_i|x_i,\theta)\big)p(\theta)\over\int_\theta \big(\prod_{i=1}^mp(y_i|x_i,\theta)\big)p(\theta)d\theta}
\end{align}
$$

I understand the first step is Bayes' theorem, but use the same theorem and chain rule for conditional probability to $p(S|\theta)$, should we get something like this:
$$
p(S|\theta)=\big(\prod_{i=1}^mp(x_i,y_i|\theta)\big)=\big(\prod_{i=1}^mp(y_i|x_i,\theta)p(x_i|\theta)\big)
$$
there are extra $p(x_i|\theta)$ terms compared to their form, do I make a mistake or miss something?

I also wonder do they use naive Naive Bayes (NB) assumption which mentioned in the previous [note](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes-spring2019/cs229-notes2.pdf) to get $p(S|\theta)$, for let a data point in training set as $z_i = (x_i,y_i)$, $p(S|\theta)$ become $p(z_1,z_2,...,z_m|\theta)=p(z_1|\theta)p(z_2|z_1,\theta)p(z_3|z_1,z_2,\theta)...p(z_m|z_1,z_2,...,z_{m-1},\theta)$, which may need assume $z_i,z_j$ are conditionally independent on $\theta$ to arrive the reduced form in their note.

Comment: I don't know, $(x_i, y_i)$ is just a traing example. They mentioned below for bayesian logistic regression, so $x_i$ may be the feature, and $y_i$ is label.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment before. To get the form of the equation they did, you don't need any conditional independence assumption between $y$ and $x$, only an assumption of unconditional independence of $x$ on $\theta$. It's true that they don't explicitly state that independence in the source (that I saw), which I suppose is technically a mistake. Though that's usually the case for a data set where $x$ is a feature and $y$ is a target.